# Volume control for ios in flex mobile 4.5 or phone gap

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, flex-mobile

I am trying to develop an application for IOS in which the application needs to have control over the phone's volume.

Please do suggest if flash 4.5 mobile or phonegap is suitable for the following requirements.

- Increase/decrease volume
- Mute
- Play audio files

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap has media module, record/play:

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html

Also there seems to be a few plugins on related topics:

- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone
- AudioRecord, SoundPlug, VolumeSlider

Answer (score 0):

Using flex 4.5, you can do all of these tasks:

- [play sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_07.html)
- [volume control (including muting)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_12.html)